# flask dynamic post url

Tags: python, url, flask

I've built a nested drop down menus on my HTML and based on what user clicks inside nested dropdown, I want it to change the default value inside WTF form and post it to database.

So I have multiple different views pointing to one 'post' view. These multiple different views are different menus in my nested dropdown menus.

**views**

```
@app.route('/first_drop_down')
def first_drop_down():
   return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/post_something/first/')
@app.route('/second_drop_down')
def second_drop_down():
   return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/post_something/second/')
@app.route('/post_something/<some_parameter>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_something(some_parameter)
   some_form = SomeForm()
   if some_parameter == 'first':
     some_form = SomeForm(field_a = some_parameter)
   elif some_parameter == 'second':
     some_form = SomeForm(field_a = some_parameter )
   if some_form.validate_on_submit():
     .
     .
     .
     .
     insert to db
     return redirect(url_for('index'))
   return render_template('user_input.html', some_paramter = some_paramter)
```

So the problem that I'm having is that I keep getting 404 right after I press submit on my form. And when doing get request on post_something view, the url is /post_something/first/ but after pressing the submit button the url changes to /post_something// , so the url is empty for post and I'm guessing thats why it is throwing 404.
Even though I kind of assume why this is happening, I am kind of stuck of what to do to maintain that url when posting. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is in your HTML code. Could you post the part of it with form and dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

from the [flask api documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/)， you will notice

`1. If a rule ends with a slash and is requested without a slash by the user, the user is automatically redirected to the same page with a trailing slash attached.
2. If a rule does not end with a trailing slash and the user requests the page with a trailing slash, a 404 not found is raised.`

Now that you have defined:

`@app.route('/post_something/<some_parameter>', methods=['GET','POST'])`

you should use `/post_something/first` in your form； Or use `url_for('post_something')` instead.